# Orderby Desc in Eloquent Laravel for related table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

I get property 'image' of non-object error while trying to rearrange the order by which the data of two tables are being retrieved.

Here is my code for userController@index

```
$users = User::orderBy('id', 'desc')->with('profile')->paginate(2);
return view('multiauth::admin.user')->with('users', $users);
```

Code for admin.user view

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
                  <tr>
                    <td class="sort-image">{{$user->first_name}}</td>
                    <td class="sort-name">{{$user->last_name}}</td>
                    <td class="sort-name">{{$user->email}}</td>
                    <td class="sort-name">{{$user->account_type}}</td>
                    <td class="sort-name">{{$user->account_status}}</td>
                    <td class="sort-phone">{{$user->profile->image}}</td>
                    <td class="sort-email">{{$user->profile->business_name}}</td>
                    <td class="sort-address">{{$user->profile->address}}</td>
                    <td class="sort-city">{{$user->profile->city}}</td>
                    <td class="sort-state">{{$user->profile->state}}</td>
                    <td class="sort-country">{{$user->profile->country}}</td>
                    <td class="sort-zip">{{$user->profile->postal}}</td>
                    <td class="sort-date" data-date="1628071164">{{$user->profile->dob}}</td>
                    <td class="sort-phone">{{$user->profile->phone}}</td>
                    <td class="sort-name">{{$user->profile->facebook}}</td>
                    <td class="sort-name">{{$user->profile->linkedin}}</td>
                    <td class="sort-name">{{$user->profile->twitter}}</td>
                    <td class="sort-name">{{$user->profile->instagram}}</td>
                    <td class="sort-name">{{$user->profile->website}}</td>
                    <td> <a href="#" class="btn btn-white"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-pencil" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                      <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
                      <path d="M4 20h4l10.5 -10.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 -4 -4l-10.5 10.5v4"></path>
                      <line x1="13.5" y1="6.5" x2="17.5" y2="10.5"></line>
                  </svg></a>
                  </td>
                  <td> <a href="#" class="btn btn-white"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-trash" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                      <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
                      <line x1="4" y1="7" x2="20" y2="7"></line>
                      <line x1="10" y1="11" x2="10" y2="17"></line>
                      <line x1="14" y1="11" x2="14" y2="17"></line>
                      <path d="M5 7l1 12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h8a2 2 0 0 0 2 -2l1 -12"></path>
                      <path d="M9 7v-3a1 1 0 0 1 1 -1h4a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3"></path>
                  </svg></a>
                  </td>
                    
                  </tr>
                  @endforeach
```

Code for User Model

```
 public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
}
```

Code for Profile Model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

I'm using laravel 8. What I'm I missing please?

Comment: Can you post the Model User and Profile ?

Comment: @MochamadAkbar I just did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it's not a syntax error, that the user records in the database are not properly related to the profile. i.e Userid column in the Profiles table is not related to the id in the Users table.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because if a user does not belong to a profile then...

```
$user->profile === null;
```

There by $user->profile->image will throw an error.

There are two things you can do.

PHP8 has a feature which is the question mark operator.

```
$user?->profile?->image
```

The question mark operator is syntax that is basically the same as

```
isset($user->profile) && isset($user->profile->image)
```

The other thing you can do is to add a constraint to your query that will only return users that belong to a profile.

```
User::whereHas('profile')->with('profile')->get();
```